# How to add global base generic class for gRPC client in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, grpc, grpc-web

Is it possible to create a generic class for gRPC client side in .net core?
I want to create a base structure for grpc service/client that contains interface.
can you help me?
Thank you

Comment: Are you going to show us what you have already?

Comment: I have a clean architect project and I want to add a base class for grpc to pass channel info, client info or TRequest, TResult. but I dont know how can I add this class
@DavidG